# How do I create a date/time till now from a timestamp in hours:minute format (HH:mm) with javascript in React app

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, date-fns

From the backend I get a timestamp when a post has been created `timestamp :  1688726557`.

In my React app I have a list with the latest posts. I have to add the *emphasized text*date time till now, like:

- 10:04 Blog post one
- 09:38 Blog post two
- 07:30 Blog post three
  // etc

I am using [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started) in my app. I can't find a way to do this. With `formatDistanceToNowStrict` for example:

```
export const formatTimeToNow = (timestamp: number) =>
  formatDistanceToNowStrict(new Date(timestamp * 1000), {
    unit: 'hour',
    locale: nl,
  });
```

I get as output `22 uur`. So in words instead of hours and minutes `HH:mm` format?

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

if what's coming from backend really timestamp only, not with date in, try this function :

```js
const tm = 1688726557;
console.log(msToHM(tm));

function msToHM(ms) {
  ms = parseInt(ms);
  const dt = new Date(ms);
  return formatLeading0(dt.getHours()) + ':' + formatLeading0(dt.getMinutes());
}

function formatLeading0(nb) {
  let nb_str = nb + '';
  if (nb_str.length === 1) {
    nb_str = '0' + nb_str;
  }
  return nb_str;
}

function HMtoMS(hm) {
  const minToMs = 60 * 1000;
  const hoursToMs = 60 * 60 * 1000;
  const ar = hm.split(':');
  return parseInt(ar[0]) * hoursToMs + parseInt(ar[1]) * minToMs;
}
```

But I think you have to multiply your value by 1000
so perhaps tm should be :

```
const tm = 1688726557 * 1000;
```

I've also added the invert conversion from HH:MM to ms

Comment: by the way I made a mistake and put the function which convert "real" full date in ms (epoch time from jan 1 1970) to formatted hours, minutes... So try it

Comment: @meez I made a change and put a snippet, check comment at the end

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. It has to be just the date but then formatted to show only the time. I can do that easily with date-fns (which I already use in the project):
`export const testDate = (timestamp: number) => {
  // return format(new Date(timestamp * 1000), 'MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm', { locale: nl });
  return format(new Date(timestamp * 1000), 'HH:mm', { locale: nl });
};`. Thanks anyway. Maybe can you remove your answer then I will delete my question here. Thanks